# Difference between periodic and recurring job in JobScheduler

Tags: android, job-scheduling

What is the difference between recurring and periodic job in Firebase JobScheduler? I can't find any detailed documentation about recurring flag in its API.

**A little background**: Since Android Oreo restricted broadcast receivers including the one for changed network state, I am looking for a way to report information based on currently connected wifi network. I don't want to waste user's battery by setting up too frequent periodic job but I need that information in reaction to connected wifi relatively quickly, in a matter of units of minutes.. I was hoping that recurring job would fire off when set up constraints changed, but I can't find any confirmation for this, or any other information regarding recurring jobs for that matter